# Laravel get sum of sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm using laravel framework, very newbie with it.
I have multiple records in my php application, something like this:

```
"[{"balance":20,"account_number":"1"},
{"balance":80,"account_number":"1"}
{"balance":20,"account_number":"2"}]"
```

I need to `SUM` the total balance of account_number.

So it should be:

```
account_number1 - balance 100
account_number2 - balance 20
```

I have tried

```
>>> $orders = DB::table('demo_trades')->select('balance', DB::raw('SUM(balance)'))->groupBy('account_number')->get()->toJson();
```

How I can do it?

Comment: You can use aggregate function predefined in DB like this `DB::table('demo_trades')->sum('balance')->groupBy('account_number')->get()->toJson();`

Answer (score 1):

Ok thx guys how helped me

i did it

`$users = DB::table('demo_trades')->select(DB::raw('sum(balance) as balance, account_number'))->groupBy('account_number')->get()->toJson();`

Answer (score 0):

You need Laravel [Aggregates queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#aggregates)

```
$orders = DB::table('demo_trades')
        ->sum('demo_trades.balance')
        ->groupBy('account_number')->get();
```

Comment: @BillalAhmed i have got PHP Error:  Call to a member function groupBy() on float on line 1